# Include xml from another file with contents from parent file

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

Is it possible to insert contents of another xml file (child xml) to a parent xml with updated attributes -- strictly using xml or xslt?  Or do I have to use python to generate the xml.

So for example lets say I have a parent xml with contents:

```
<root>
    <parent1 value="parent1">
        # get contents of child.xml
    </parent1>
    <parent2 value="parent2">
        # get contents of child.xml
    </parent2>
</root>
```

child.xml has contents:

```
<root>
    <child1 value="child1"/>
    <child2 value="child2"/>
</root>
```

which I could do with include, but I also want to update the value.  So the final xml I want is:

```
<root>
    <parent1 value="parent1">
        <child1 value="parent1_child1"/>
        <child2 value="parent1_child2"/>
    </parent1>
    <parent2 value="parent2">
        <child1 value="parent2_child1"/>
        <child2 value="parent2_child2"/>
    </parent2>
</root>
```

Where the value of the child is update based on the parent value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the document() function to refer to another XML file. You could implement it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="childDoc" select="document('child.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:variable name="currentParent" select="."/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="$childDoc/root/child">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="value" select="concat($currentParent/@value,'_',@value)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGr
(I have put the document in a variable for testing purposes.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  This does work for your example, but the parent is not always parent, its could be parent1, parent2, something1, something2, etc.  How could I update the solution to work with a variable parent tag?

Comment: Your template needs to match to some name. Is the first part of the element name always the same? One way to do it would be to use match="parent1 | parent2 | something1 | something2" but that won't work if you have an infinite number of element names.

Comment: It will be about 20 values maybe, but definitely better than repeating all the child elements 20 times

Answer (score 2):

You can load the "child" document with the [`document()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-document) function and assign it to a variable in the stylesheet and then mix in with the "parent" content:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:variable name="child-doc" select="document('child.xml')"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$child-doc/root/*" mode="child">
                <xsl:with-param name="prefix" tunnel="yes" select="@value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="child">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="child"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="root/*/@value" mode="child">
        <xsl:param name="prefix" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="value" select="string-join(($prefix, .), '_')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```